# undefined method 'authorize' with Pundit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pundit

I've installed the gem Pundit in my Rails app, and have followed the instructions in the README carefully.

However, when I use authorize in any of my controllers, I get the error message "undefined method 'authorize' for .

Also, when I try to use "policy" in a view, I get the error "undefined method 'policy'".

It's as if Pundit weren't installed at all!

I've included Pundit in my Application Controller.

I have an ApplicationPolicy file with all of my policies, then policy files for each type of record that inherit from the Application Policy.

For some reason, I can't paste any of my code into this question, so I'm hoping I've included enough information!

I'd appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: Pundit is "just plain Ruby," so including it in your Application Controller should be all that you need. Are you sure that you spelled everything correctly? Is `include Pundit` the first line below the `ApplicationController` declaration. Also, are your controllers inheriting from the `ApplicationController`?

Comment: Thank you! These thoughts were helpful.

Comment: By chance, are you using Clearance for authentication? If so, Devise uses a method called `authorize` that conflicts with Pundit. In my application controller, I have this `alias_method :require_login, :authorize` and the next line is my `include Pundit`. Also, ensure that you are calling authorize on an instance of a model (i.e., `authorize @my_var`)

Comment: When used in a Rails Engine, we had to `require 'pundit'` in the namespaced ApplicationController

Answer (score 3):

I have recently used pundit and it worked like a charm. 
your error messages makes me infer that you've not run install 
**rails g pundit:install** or your policies file are not in correct directories.

or if they are then Just restarting the server should fix this. Hopefully.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I was missing `include Pundit` at the top of my ApplicationController. Adding that line fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate a default policy file for your application with the **pundit:install generator**.

```
rails g pundit:install
  create  app/policies/application_policy.rb
```